# How to stop a streaming audio

Tags: vb.net, sapi

How do I stop a audio stream once I play it using sapi. Do I have to skip the whole set of sentences ?

Edit : How to stop it once I have paused the audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
Private Sub start()
objVoice.Speak "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", SVSFlagsAsync
End Sub

Private Sub stop()
objVoice.Speak "", SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak
End Sub
```

Please read about [SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Once if I pause the audio and then try to stop, it returns an error

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz unpause it first before you purge...?